# comparar dos variables o datos con python STR

Tags: python, python-3.x

tengo un problema con dos variables, no logro hacer funcionar el if and else, una de ellas yo mismo la asigo, la otra es extraida de un archivo o log que cree antes de ejecutar este script, la variable mmr = 800 la variable elo_bad = 1845

las dos variables al usar type() me dice tipo str pero no logro compararlas y que me diga elo alto cuando el elo del jugador esta por encima de 800 mmr

si tengo algun error en el resto de codigo les agradeceria si me corrigen para que se haga de la mejor manera, les dejo el log tambien.

script python3 ---------

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
#-------------------------------------------------librerias
import requests
import os
import re

#--------------------------------------analisis de tada log
try:
    #------------------------------------------regex
    palabra = "elo.:[0-9]{3,4}"
    #------------------------------------leer data.log
    with open ('data.log', 'r', encoding="utf-8") as texto:
        for x in texto:
            #--------------------------------buscar regex en data.log
            buscar = re.findall(palabra,x)
            #print(buscar[0])

            #------------------------------------eliminar simbolos []
            elo = buscar[0]

            #-----------------------------------------guardar log elo
            #elo = open('elo.log', 'w')
            #elo.write(str(buscar[0]))
            #elo.close()

            #---------------------------------------eliminar comillas
            elo_clear=elo.replace('"','')
            #print(elo_clear)

            #----------------------------------------regex numero elo
            regex_bad_elo = "[0-9]{3,4}"
            #---------------------------guardar numero elo en elo.log
            save_elo = open('elo.log', 'w')
            save_elo.write(str(buscar[0]))
            save_elo.close()

            with open ('elo.log', 'r', encoding="utf-8") as elo_w:
                for y in elo_w:
                    search_elo = re.findall(regex_bad_elo,y)
                    #print(buscar[0])
                    elo_bad = search_elo[0]

                    print("elo jugador: ",elo_bad)

                    mmr = '800'

                    print()
                    if elo_bad <= mmr:
                        print('Atencio elo bajo')
                    else:
                        print('buen elo')

except FileNotFoundError:
    print("archivo no encontrado")
```

data.log con la data ----

```
b'{"slp":{"total":552,"claimableTotal":0,"lastClaimedItemAt":1643730176,"rawTotal":8115,"rawClaimableTotal":7563,"todaySoFar":73,"yesterdaySLP":191,"average":94},"leaderboard":{"winRate":"0","winTotal":0,"drawTotal":0,"loseTotal":0,"elo":1845,"rank":122413,"name":"Dave  | \xf0\x9f\x90\xba Astro NFT Gaming"},"adventure":{"gained_slp":0,"max_slp":50}}'
```

Comment: no puedes hacer `elo_bad <= mmr` cuando `mmr='800'`. Debes convertir esos strings a número con `int`. Además no es más fácil cargar ese JSON a python como diccionario?

Comment: Christian se refiere a que podría ser más fácil usar el modulo [json](https://docs.python.org/es/3.9/library/json.html) que ya procesa el json. No es necesario usar regex. Eso convierte numeros del json en numeros de Python, objects en diccionarios, arrays en listas, etc

Comment: es que ese formato no me lo toma con json, no se porque, ya intente convertir a entero los dos strings pero tampoco funciona el if

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supongo que el motivo por el cual el if no se activa la condicion es porque olvidaste convertir a numero sea entero o decimal ambas variables evaluadas:elo_bad y mmr. por lo que en cada iteracion, al contener ambas variables strings, el interprete teniendo que comparar dos strings las compara en terminos de cual tiene menos o igual cantidad de caracteres. si pasas a entero ambas variables en el lugar talvez se solucione.

Para tu conocimiento, toda informacion contenida en un archivo de texto siempre sera un tdato tipo strin "str" y siempre saldra como string "str", por lo que si este es un numero tendras que convertirlo cuando corresponda si deseas emplearlo como numero.
Entonces cuando abres el archivo elo.log para lectura, toda la informacion que extraes de esta es string

´´´

import requests
import os
import re

try:
palabra = "elo.:[0-9]{3,4}"

```
with open ('data.log', 'r', encoding="utf-8") as texto:
    for x in texto:
        #--------------------------------buscar regex en data.log
        buscar = re.findall(palabra,x)
        #print(buscar[0])

        #------------------------------------eliminar simbolos []
        elo = buscar[0]

        #-----------------------------------------guardar log elo
        #elo = open('elo.log', 'w')
        #elo.write(str(buscar[0]))
        #elo.close()

        #---------------------------------------eliminar comillas
        elo_clear=elo.replace('"','')
        #print(elo_clear)

        #----------------------------------------regex numero elo
        regex_bad_elo = "[0-9]{3,4}"
        #---------------------------guardar numero elo en elo.log
        save_elo = open('elo.log', 'w')
        save_elo.write(str(buscar[0]))
        save_elo.close()

        with open ('elo.log', 'r', encoding="utf-8") as elo_w:
            for y in elo_w:
                search_elo = re.findall(regex_bad_elo,y)
                #print(buscar[0])
                elo_bad = search_elo[0]

                print("elo jugador: ",elo_bad)

                mmr = '800'

                print()
                if int(elo_bad) <= int(mmr):   #AQUI ESTA HECHA LA MODIFICACION!
                     print('Atencio elo bajo')
                else:
                    print('buen elo')
```

except FileNotFoundError:

```
print("archivo no encontrado")
```

´´´